# Does 1 ViewModel really have 1 View?

Tags: asp.net, mvvm, view, user-controls, viewmodel

its said that 1 ViewModel has 1 View.

1 View is for me a UserControl. What if my UserControl has different areas filled with data from different entities, do I have then several Views and need to build several ViewModels?

e.g: I display in a UserControl 3 entities: customer(listbox),order(datagrid),product(datagrid). Each of those "data areas" has add+remove buttons and textboxes to enter data.

Actually each of those "data areas" are put in its own GRID having so the posibility to set a individual datacontext.

1.) Should I now create 3 ViewModels CustomerVM,OrderVM and ProductVM?
2.) Are those 3 "data areas" seen as an own sort of separated View, although I have not put them in 3 UserControls.xaml files ???
3.) When this one UserControl is inside a TabControl`s tabpage where do I load the 3 entities related data? Inside the MainViewModel? I want to show/load that data only when the user clicks the tabheader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can do all that in the one viewmodel. The job of the viewmodel is to hold the data for the view, and if necessary transform that data so the view can consume it. There is nothing that says a viewmodel has to hold specific types of information, i.e. there are no rules that state "it may only hold customer info and not order info".

Having said that, there is also no reason why the viewmodel cannot be consumed by several different views (give them all different instances, of course) - this would show that you have a good separation of concerns between your views and viewmodel. Personally, i code my viewmodels so that they have no idea that the view exists. There is also no reason why the view has to consume everything that the viewmodel exposes, although binding a CustomerView to a CustomerOrderProductViewModel is going a little too far.

**Edit:** let me explain that last paragraph a little more.

`Example 1: i have a new V which shows customer information, and i have an existing VM which has customer info AND order info`

I would be reluctant to use this VM for this V, because while it does have the client info i need, it has too much info - i'm using the VM out of the context is was originally intended for.

`Example 2: i have a VM that contains full client info, like their postal and residential address, their phone numbers, their girlfriend's names*, and a bunch of other client type info. I have a V which shows the client's name, birthday, and maybe two other properties.`

I would consider using that VM for that V, this illustrates my point that the V doesn't have to show all the info contained within the VM. This concept becomes more apparent when you change the V (as in, do some maintenance and change the UI of the view, because someone has decided that they want a bunch of fields removed and now they want to represent the client's age as an image) - i can still use the same VM, and just change the V (i could use a ValueConverter to represent the age as an image, thus avoiding a change to the VM).

`At what point would i stop using the current ClientViewModel, and write a new one that was more specific to the needs of the modified ClientView?`

There is no clear cut answer to that - it depends on the amount of time i have available to do the changes, the amount of time available for testing, and the trade-off in complexity between using a full blown Client object for the VM, and writing a new leaner version of the Client object while still retaining the old one.

*that should be a collection of independant objects incorporated in the client object, but just work with me here it's a made up example :)

Comment: The first part was clear the last paragraph is confusing ;-)

So I have one CustomerProductOrderViewModel and one View ?? You say the opposite in the last sentence:"...although binding a CustomerView to a CustomerOrderProductViewModel is going a little too far...." can you explain?

Comment: @msfanboy: slugster is saying that using a very specific view to visualize another very specific viewmodel in a completely different manner is somewhat disturbing.  Even though CustomerOrderProductViewModel might contain all of the properties of a customer, it also has significantly more information that using a simple CustomerView for that view model is not desirable.  This is a good observation and can lead to a lot of maintenance confusion down the road.

Comment: sorry Anderson but I did understand nothing what you said. REally nothing.
CustomerOrderProductViewModel would contain more than only the customers properties. It would contain also Properties of Order + Product and stuff like SelectedCustomers, SelectedProducts and SelectedOrders.

Opton 1:
1 View/UserControl.xaml - 1 DataContext - 1 ViewModel containing Customer/Order/Products Properties
Option 2:
1 View/UserControl.xaml - 3 DataContext set on each Grid/"data area" see above explanation - 3 ViewModel each containing Properties of Customer, Order, Products.

Just tell me is that ok? YES/NO ?

Comment: To clarify whether i would use multiple VMs on one larger V: it all depends upon the complexity. Would having one VM be too complex due to the nature of the data? Or would having multiple smaller VMs be architecturally pure, but a real PITA because the only thing each VM contains is a generic list of objects (i.e. List<Product> is the only property on the VM).